# Mis-aligned free translations in gb4e

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

When there is an example with a number more than three digits, the free translation line is too far to the left in `gb4e` examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss4e}
\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \exi{(10.159)} \gll    b\'u \`a k\H{o} k\`am t\`aha k\'{\i}    \\
            cl2 {\sc ds} (b)hold (a)break (a)scatter cl7      \\
    \glt    ``They broke it off.'' (Missong)
    \z
\end{document}
```

[image]

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Comment: Can you please [post a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I am not able to get your code to compile.

Comment: @Adam i cleaned up the code to make it a MWE. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`gb4e`- documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/gb4e/gb4e-doc.pdf):

> All example-list commands have an optional argument which allows you
>   to set the labelwidth to, e.g., the widest label to come (...). So,
>   `\begin{exe}[(234)]` will set the labelwidth to the width of
>   “(234)”—which is also the default. (...) The default labelwidth for
>   the exe- environment can also be changed globally by issuing a
>   `\exewidth{<string>}` command in the preamble of your document

So, for your example, both of the following work (I also suggest to use small-caps as already demonstrated by Adam in his answer, as well as separate the language name from the translation with `\hfill` unless explicitly required otherwise):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss4e}
\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}[(10.159)]
        \exi{(10.159)} \gll    b\'u \`a k\H{o} k\`am t\`aha k\'{\i}    \\
            \textsc{cl}2 \textsc{ds} (\textsc{b})hold (\textsc{a})break (\textsc{a})scatter \textsc{cl}7      \\
    \glt    ``They broke it off.'' \hfill (Missong)
    \z
\end{document}
```

**or**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss4e}
    \exewidth{(10.159)}
\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \exi{(10.159)} \gll    b\'u \`a k\H{o} k\`am t\`aha k\'{\i}    \\
            \textsc{cl}2 \textsc{ds} (\textsc{b})hold (\textsc{a})break (\textsc{a})scatter \textsc{cl}7  \\
    \glt    ``They broke it off.'' \hfill (Missong)\\
    \z
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I could have sworn I had read the manual already ;-)

Comment: On top of using `\hfill`, I find it's usually prettiest to have the language name on the first line. This is possible by doing `\hfill \raisebox{2\baselineskip}[0][0]{(Missong)}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can achieve the output that you want by adding the translation line as an unnumbered example with the optional judgment argument empty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\exi{(10.159)}{\label{exArgStructAb60e2}
\gll    b\'u \`a k\H{o} k\`am t\`aha k\'{\i} \\
        \textsc{cl}2 \textsc{ds} (\textsc{b})hold (\textsc{a})break (\textsc{a})scatter \textsc{cl}7 \\}
\sn[]{``They broke it off.'' (Missong)}

\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, if, for whatever reason you need the main example to have a judgment, you can also use this approach, which is another hack, more than anything:

```
\begin{exe}

\exi{(10.159)}[*]{\label{exArgStructAb60e2}
\gll    b\'u \`a k\H{o} k\`am t\`aha k\'{\i} \\
        \textsc{cl}2 \textsc{ds} (\textsc{b})hold (\textsc{a})break (\textsc{a})scatter \textsc{cl}7 \\}
\sn[\hphantom{000*}]{``They broke it off.'' (Missong)}

\end{exe}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe an `\hphantom` is better than guessing how many `~` are necessary. It seems that `\sn[\hphantom{000*}]` does the trick.

Comment: Although this works, since `gb4e` provides a mechanism for specifying the label width, I think JakobMST's answer is to be preferred.

Comment: On the other hand, Adam's solution shows small caps in the appropriate places, which I glossed over (no pun intended).

Comment: @JakobMST +1 for the 'inadvertent' pun!

Comment: Also, agreed @AlanMunn. This solution definitely is not that elegant. I should have looked at the documentation... Haha.